# Evaluating $\sin^{-1}(\cos(40))$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, inverse

So as the title states I have to evaluate

$\sin^{-1}(\cos(40))$

In my textbook they answer it as following:

$\sin^{-1}(\cos(40))=90-\cos^{-1}(\cos(40))=50$

I'm however a little confounded over their answer.

As I recall this is the complementary angle identity but I don't really understand why it is used, considering is within the bound of [-1,1]

Would be extremely grateful if somebody could expand. If my question is unclear, I would be more than happy to further clearify.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you are using degrees, please make it clear by using $40^\circ, 50^\circ$ and $90^\circ$. I would say that $$\arcsin\cos(40)=-40 +\frac{25\pi}{2},$$ otherwise.

Comment: How did you arrive at that conclusion?

Comment: $\cos(40)=\sin\left(\frac{25\pi}{2}-40\right)$ and $\frac{25\pi}{2}-40$ is close enough to $0$ to be part of the range of the $\arcsin$ function.

Comment: $\arcsin\cos(40^\circ)$ is the amplitude of the acute angle whose sine equals $\cos(40^\circ)=\sin(50^\circ)$, i.e. $50^\circ$.

Comment: what exactly do you mean "it's within the bound of $[-1,1]$"?

Comment: This complementary angle identity is just that... an identity.  Consider any right triangle's two non-right angles.  The complementary relation between them doesn't depend on anything other than $180$ degrees makes any triangle in standard euclidian geometry

Comment: @AmateurMathGuy I was thinking because cos(x) = y and y is bounded [-1,1] and cos(40) resides within those bounds. Why could't you just then find cos(40) on the x-axis. I really should've expanded on that during in my original question. Sorry about that.

Comment: @oxodo Note that $\cos(40^\circ)=\sin(50^\circ) \implies \arcsin(\cos(40^\circ))=50^\circ$.

Comment: @oxodo no worries.  Thinking of the graph does help in a lot of ways but here you can either think more symbolically, or observe that while the domain of the $\arcsin$ function is $[-1,1]$, so is the range of both the cosine and the sine functions.

Comment: $\sin(x)=\cos(90^\circ-x)$ so $\arcsin(x)=90^\circ-\arccos(x)$ though one should tend to use $\pi/2$ instead of $90^\circ$ whenever possible.

Answer (score 6):

Does the following help?

$$\begin{align}
\arcsin {\cos \theta}&=\omega \\
\cos \theta &=\sin \omega \\
\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta\right) &= \sin \omega \\
\end{align}$$

also there's this

$$\begin{align}
\sin \theta &= \cos \left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta \right) \\
&\text{if}  \ \ \theta =\arcsin \Omega \quad \ldots \quad \text{then} \\
\Omega&=\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\arcsin \Omega \right) \\
\arccos \Omega&=\frac{\pi}{2}-\arcsin \Omega \\
\color{red}{\arcsin \Omega} \ & =\color{red}{\frac{\pi}{2}-\arccos \Omega} \\
\frac{\pi}{2}&=\arcsin \Omega + \arccos \Omega
\end{align}$$

Comment: Right. So could I reason as follows: 

$cos^\circ{40}=sin(\frac{pi}{2}-40^\circ)$

and 

$sin^{-1}(sin(\frac{pi}{2}-40^\circ)=(\frac{pi}{2}-40^\circ)$

Because of the cancellation identities?

Comment: yes.  It's the same as in the above taking the arcsine of both sides an arriving at $$\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta=\omega$$ such that theta is $40$ degrees and omega is the answer you seek

Comment: Alright! thank you. I'm still unsure how the author arrived at $90-\cos^{-1}(\cos(40))$ specifically $\cos^{-1}(\cos(40))$ all I know is that he applied  thecomplementary angle identity to get:

 $ \sin^{-1}(\cos(40))=90-\cos^{-1}(\cos(40))=50$

Anyhow, thanks!

Comment: They could have taken $$\cos \theta=\sin \omega \quad \to \quad \cos \theta=\cos \left( \frac{\pi}{2}-\omega \right)$$ instead?

Comment: This identity: $$\arcsin x=\frac{\pi}{2} - \arccos x$$ may more directly apply here.  Set $\quad x=\cos{\theta} \quad$.  The book likely just resorted to that....?

Answer (score 0):

Let $ \alpha =\sin^{-1}(\cos(40))$. That is $\sin(\alpha )=\cos(40)$. Using the formula $\sin(   \alpha ) = \cos(  \pi/2 -\alpha  )$ results in $\alpha =50$ . Note that we are working in degree mode and using complementary angles.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. But how would you arrive to the author's answer if you would've to write it down? Thank you btw

Comment: It depends on what is known and what is not known at this course. Can we use formulas like$ sin(\pi /2 - \alpha )= cos(\alpha )$?

Comment: See if the edited version works better.